# Swagger Integration in Laravel 5.7. Facing Problem in swagger.sh file

Tags: swagger, laravel-5.7

How to convert this Linux command into windows so I can make it run?

```
mkdir ../public/swagger php ../vendor/bin/swagger --bootstrap ./swagger-constants.php --output ../public/swagger ./swagger-v1.php ../app/Http/Controllers
```

Comment: I think `makedir` also works in cmd

Comment: no it's not rather I found another package and my problem is resolved and swagger is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix my issue by installing packaging from this git:https://github.com/appointer/swaggervel which is working fine with laravel 6 also.